# Como alterar o diretório /wp-admin/ do WordPress? e como alterar as URLs do admin do WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Gostaria de alterar o nome do diretório `/wp-admin/` para por exemplo `/admin/` no WordPress, porém não tenho ideia de como fazer isso da forma certa. Vejo que esse tipo de alteração não é muito comum.

Gostaria também de alterar algumas URLs do WordPress que estão em inglês e passá-las ao português.

Ex:

> Para criar um novo Post: `meusite.com/wp-admin/post-new.php`
>
> Para criar uma nova Página: `meusite.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page`

Esses são alguns exemplos.

O correto seria:

> Para criar um novo Post: `meusite.com/wp-admin/novo-post.php`
>
> Para criar uma nova Página: `meusite.com/wp-admin/novo-post.php?post_tipo=pagina`

Queria alguma solução que me permitisse tal funcionalidade, de preferência **Plugins**.

Comment: Resposta curta: ***desista,* é impossível**. Uma resposta longa precisa de bastante pesquisa; alguma coisa dá pra fazer, mas não muito e não sem dor-de-cabeça.

Comment: Pois é @brasofilo eu também achei que não seria muito fácil.

Comment: Pelo menos o `/wp-admin/` já tá de bom tamanho, :/

Comment: Se me lembro bem, caso você esteja usando Apache e tenha total controle do vhost, é possível se conseguir algo desse tipo usando redirects. Um dos tipos possíveis de redirecionamento o faz no próprio servidor, sem enviar código HTTP algum pro cliente e portanto sem mudar a URL exibida. O problema então seria fazer as páginas geradas pelo wordpress linkarem pra versão traduzida. Minha única sugestão nesse sentido é incluir um JavaScript em toda página que "varra" o HTML inteiro substituindo o destino dos links conforme um mapeamento. Possível, sim, mas não recomendo...

Comment: Você pode criar uma regra com HTACCESS para acessar a url `/admin/` mantendo a pasta `/wp-admin/`, mas renomear a pasta acho que complica pela 'mecânica' do WP, assim como mudar as URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito interessante o [plugin recomendado pelo @moraleida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27612/como-alterar-o-diret%C3%B3rio-wp-admin-do-wordpress-e-como-alterar-as-urls-do-admi/27644#27644), tem cara de *must use*.
Estive analizando o código e a interface, e vejo que tem uma limitação: ele só esconde a URL `/wp-admin` e as URL de login e registro **para os visitantes que não estão logados**. Uma vez logado, o usuário navega nos links do `/wp-admin` normalmente.

De tudo que já li no [WordPress Developers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) e no [[wp-hackers]](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/), e também do que já testei com o material postado no WPSE e SOen, dá pra dizer que é praticamente impossível fazer uma área administrativa livre da URL `/wp-admin/*`.

<sub><sup><opiniao></sup></sub> Em vez de esconder do cliente que está usando WordPress, acho que é preferível levantar a bola e dizer que é uma plataforma de código aberto em expansão exponencial e com uma comunidade de desenvolvedores, administradores e usuários imensa. <sub><sup></opiniao></sup></sub>

Ando trabalhando com [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) para [WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) e é possível construir uma app administrativa (web ou mobile) usando essa conexão. É importante ter a segurança bem atada, e vai dar bastante trabalho criar uma interface do zero.

Do lado do ***front end***, dá para esconder o `/wp-content/*` das URLs usando as técnicas descritas em [*Steps to Take to Hide the Fact a Site is Using WordPress?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1507/12615)

Comment: Não é para cliente, é para meu site. Tenho alguns autores e quero esconder essas URLS.

Comment: Eu já escondi todas, a única que está faltando é a `wp-admin`.

Comment: Pois é, adoraria estar errado, mas acho que não dá.

Comment: É uma pena amigo. :(

Answer (score 3):

Não é o melhor jeito de responder, mas como vc pediu um plugin, o [Better Wp Security](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) faz isso. Certifique-se de ler com cuidado as instruções, se não ele VAI te trancar pra fora do site. **vc foi avisado**

Comment: Isso já aconteceu comigo uma vez, só que com outro plugin.

Comment: por via das dúvidas, vou exportar o banco de dados via PHP My Admin